# Java generics with inner class and inner interface

Tags: java, generics

Below I have a generic OuterClass, an InnerClass that use OuterClass generics and 
non-generic InnerInterface.

```
public class OuterClass<E> {

    public class InnerClass  {

        public E someMethod() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public interface InnerInterface{
        public void onEvent(OuterClass.InnerClass innerClass);
    }
}
```

In the main method below, I use two instance of OuterClass, o1 parameterized with , and o2 with .
My annonymous inner class myListener tries to use the generic type of the outer class (E).
The code as it is below does not compile (Integer i = innerClass.someMethod() - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Integer).

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OuterClass<Integer> o1 = new OuterClass<Integer>();
        OuterClass<String> o2 = new OuterClass<String>();

        OuterClass.InnerInterface innerInterface = new OuterClass.InnerInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(InnerClass innerClass) {
                Integer i = innerClass.someMethod();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I would like to express that myListener is for o1, and should use E = Integer, without repeating it (without repeating , I already say it when declaring o1). Is that possible?

Many thanks!
Faton.

Comment: Your interface method needs to be genericized, too.

Answer (score 16):

An inner interface or enum is implicitely static, and static members are not parameterized with the type parameters of the outer class. So `InnerInterface` should look like this:

```
public interface InnerInterface<E> {
    void onEvent(OuterClass<E>.InnerClass innerClass);
}
```

Note that the `E` parameter of `InnerInterface` is *not* the same as the `E` parameter of `OuterClass`.

Comment: Perhaps, then, it would be better not to call it E?

Comment: Thank you Laurent. It would work, but I've to repeat <Integer> because it's a different E. My question was "is it possible to reuse the first E = <Integer>", and prevent redeclaring <Integer> for the interface ?

Comment: Probably not a great idea to use the same identifier for the generic parameter.

Comment: @Faton Then the answer is no.

Comment: @Tom Maybe, but the type parameter of `InnerInterface` has the very same meaning as the `E` of `Outerclass`, and I think using the same name makes that relation obvious.

Comment: @Laurent Pireyn In terms of code, it is completely independent. Now if the didn't have an intersecting scope (sensible) then it wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As always, non-`private` nested types don't help keeping things simple. Push the boat out and create some new files, even if your IDe works against you.

Anyway, static members of a class do not share the generic parameters of the outer class. This is important for the behaviour of fields, and allows more flexibility on static nested types (such as `InnerInterface`) even if you don't want it. So, in your case, you need to give your (static) nested interface a generic parameter. For $deity's sake, use a different identifier!

```
public class OuterClass<E> {
    public class InnerClass  {
        public E someMethod() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public interface InnerInterface<T> {
        void onEvent(OuterClass<T>.InnerClass innerClass);
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OuterClass<Integer> o1 = new OuterClass<Integer>();
        OuterClass<String> o2 = new OuterClass<String>();

        OuterClass.InnerInterface<Integer> innerInterface =
            new OuterClass.InnerInterface<Integer>() 
       {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(OuterClass<Integer>.InnerClass innerClass) {
                Integer i = innerClass.someMethod();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

(I've also qualified `InnerClass` where necessary.)

Edit: It's probably worth just looking at the original anonymous inner class in isolation from the rest of the use:

```
public interface InnerInterface{
    public void onEvent(OuterClass.InnerClass innerClass);
}

    OuterClass.InnerInterface innerInterface = new OuterClass.InnerInterface() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(InnerClass innerClass) {
            Integer i = innerClass.someMethod();
        }
    };
```

`Integer` only appears once, in a place where it clearly cannot be inferred to be correct.