# Inner interface in generates errors only when outer class is parameterized? Why?

Tags: java, class, interface, static, parameterized

The abstract method getNextNode generates the error, "cannot make a static reference to the non-static type Node," but only if LinkedList is parameterized. If I remove the generic  from LinkedList the error goes away. Why?

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    Node head;
    public LinkedList() {
        head = new Node();
    }
    private class Node {

    }

    interface stuff {
        public Node getNextNode();//ERROR Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type Node
    }
}
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/5402869/1743880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you can't use a generic type without its parameter.

`Node` is actually `LinkedList<T>.Node`.  Since your interface isn't generic (interfaces don't inherit type parameters from the containing class), there is no `T` it can substitute.

You can fix this by making the `Node` class `static`, so that it doesn't inherit the type parameter from its containing class.
However, you don't actually want to do that, since the `Node` *should* be generic.

You actually need to make your interface generic as well, so that it can specify a `T`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Node` short for `LinkedList<T>.Node` and your `getNextNode()` doesn't know what `T` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    interface can't be defined in an inner class


    http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-an-interface-cant-be-defined-in-an-inner-class/56

public class Test{
interface stuff {
        public LinkedList.Node getNextNode();
    }
    public class LinkedList<T> {
        Node head;

        public LinkedList() {
            head = new Node();
        }
        private class Node {

        }
}
```